# Speed Up Excel Macro VBA Code

Tags: vba, excel

do you have any suggestion to speed up my vba code?

I'm using the UserForm to let the user check which months he wants to analize.

Once the user confirm his selection, this code compare the data and write the results (if it founds something) in the cells.

Right now, it takes 38.7 seconds to get i at 100.

Thank you in advance and best regards.

```
Private Sub Cmd1_Click()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim ult As Long
Dim myFrame As Control
Dim myCheck As Control
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
ult = Worksheets("VendutoPassato").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 StartTime = Timer
For i = 2 To 433
    If Cells(i, 4) <> "" Then
        For Each myFrame In Me.Controls
            If TypeName(myFrame) = "Frame" Then
                For Each myCheck In myFrame.Controls
                    If TypeName(myCheck) = "CheckBox" Then
                        If myCheck.Value = True Then
                            For j = 2 To ult
                                If Cells(i, 4) Like Worksheets("VendutoPassato").Cells(j, 1) And Worksheets("VendutoPassato").Cells(j, 3) Like Month(DateValue("02-" & myCheck.Caption & "-1992")) And Worksheets("VendutoPassato").Cells(j, 2) Like myFrame.Caption Then
                                    Cells(i, 14) = Cells(i, 14) + Worksheets("VendutoPassato").Cells(j, 4)
                                End If
                            Next
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    Else
        If Cells(i, 3) <> "" Then
            For Each myFrame In Me.Controls
                If TypeName(myFrame) = "Frame" Then
                    For Each myCheck In myFrame.Controls
                        If TypeName(myCheck) = "CheckBox" Then
                            If myCheck.Value = True Then
                                For j = 2 To ult
                                    If Cells(i, 3) Like Worksheets("VendutoPassato").Cells(j, 1) And Worksheets("VendutoPassato").Cells(j, 3) Like Month(DateValue("02-" & myCheck.Caption & "-1992")) And Worksheets("VendutoPassato").Cells(j, 2) Like myFrame.Caption Then
                                        Cells(i, 14) = Cells(i, 14) + Worksheets("VendutoPassato").Cells(j, 4)
                                    End If
                                Next
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If
Next
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

Comment: You access the spreadsheet **a lot**. Read the relevant data into an array first, then check against that.

Comment: Code "Speed Up" Question should be asked on [codereview.se]

Comment: Also you go through the exact same If/then statements in both if and if else sequences, I suggest you move `If Cells(i, 4) <> "" Then` and `Else If Cells(i, 3) <> "" Then` to just before `If Cells(i, 4) Like Worksheets("VendutoPassato")....`

Comment: Here is a link on this topic: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx  also, you might want to use autofilter approach if you don't want to mess with arrays. Looping through large amount of data always take very long time.

Comment: This belongs on [codereview.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do some significant improvement following the suggestions of  @tehhowch and @Middle.

Now it takes 8.75 seconds to get i at 100.

If you guys know how to optimize it even more, you're welcome!

```
Private Sub Cmd1_Click()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim ult As Long
Dim myFrame As Control
Dim myCheck As Control
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
Dim arr As Variant
Dim arrx As Variant

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

ult = Worksheets("VendutoPassato").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
arr = Worksheets("VendutoPassato").Range("A2:D" & ult)
arrx = Worksheets("Foglio1").Range("C2:D433")

For i = 1 To 432
    If arrx(i, 2) <> "" Then
        For Each myFrame In Me.Controls
            If TypeName(myFrame) = "Frame" Then
                For Each myCheck In myFrame.Controls
                    If TypeName(myCheck) = "CheckBox" Then
                        If myCheck.Value = True Then
                            For j = 1 To ult - 1
                                If arrx(i, 2) Like arr(j, 1) And arr(j, 3) Like Month(DateValue("02-" & myCheck.Caption & "-1992")) And arr(j, 2) Like myFrame.Caption Then
                                    Cells(i + 1, 14) = Cells(i + 1, 14) + arr(j, 4)
                                    Exit For
                                End If
                            Next
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    Else
        If arrx(i, 1) <> "" Then
            For Each myFrame In Me.Controls
                If TypeName(myFrame) = "Frame" Then
                    For Each myCheck In myFrame.Controls
                        If TypeName(myCheck) = "CheckBox" Then
                            If myCheck.Value = True Then
                                For j = 1 To ult - 1
                                    If arrx(i, 1) Like arr(j, 1) And arr(j, 3) Like Month(DateValue("02-" & myCheck.Caption & "-1992")) And arr(j, 2) Like myFrame.Caption Then
                                        Cells(i, 14) = Cells(i, 14) + arr(j, 4)
                                        Exit For
                                    End If
                                Next
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If
Next

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try, should be much faster:

```
Private Sub Cmd1_Click()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsVenduto As Worksheet
    Dim rVendutoData As Range
    Dim myFrame As Control
    Dim myCheck As Control
    Dim aDataIDs As Variant
    Dim aDataValues As Variant
    Dim LastDataRow As Long
    Dim DataIndex As Long
    Dim vID As Variant
    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim SecondsElapsed As Double

    StartTime = Timer

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.ActiveSheet
    Set wsVenduto = wb.Sheets("VendutoPassato")
    Set rVendutoData = wsVenduto.Range("A2", wsVenduto.Cells(wsVenduto.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    LastDataRow = wsData.Range("C:D").Find("*", wsData.Range("C1"), xlValues, xlWhole, , xlPrevious).Row
    aDataIDs = wsData.Range("C2:D" & LastDataRow).Value
    aDataValues = wsData.Range("N2").Resize(UBound(aDataIDs, 1) - LBound(aDataIDs, 1) + 1).Value

    For DataIndex = LBound(aDataIDs, 1) To UBound(aDataIDs, 1)
        vID = vbNullString
        Select Case Abs((aDataIDs(DataIndex, 2) = "")) + Abs(2 * (aDataIDs(DataIndex, 1) = ""))
            Case 0, 2:  vID = aDataIDs(DataIndex, 2)
            Case 1:     vID = aDataIDs(DataIndex, 1)
        End Select
        If Len(vID) > 0 Then
            For Each myFrame In Me.Controls
                If TypeOf myFrame Is Frame Then
                    For Each myCheck In myFrame.Controls
                        If TypeName(myCheck) = "CheckBox" Then
                            If myCheck.Value = True Then
                                aDataValues(DataIndex, 1) = aDataValues(DataIndex, 1) + WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(rVendutoData.Offset(, 3), _
                                                                                                                 rVendutoData, vID, _
                                                                                                                 rVendutoData.Offset(, 1), myFrame.Caption, _
                                                                                                                 rVendutoData.Offset(, 2), myCheck.Caption)
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next myCheck
                End If
            Next myFrame
        End If
    Next DataIndex

    wsData.Range("N2").Resize(UBound(aDataValues, 1) - LBound(aDataValues, 1) + 1).Value = aDataValues

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Unload UserForm1

    SecondsElapsed = Timer - StartTime
    MsgBox "Completed successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds."

End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like some good wizard dust but it needs some comments to explain how it provides the same functionality. Can you explain what you are doing in that case switch with the absolute values?

Comment: It's just checking if column D is populated, and if so it uses the column D value to assign to vID.  If it's not populated, it uses the column C value to assign to vID, and if neither are populated it skips that row.  Could be replicated with an If/ElseIf/Else, but in my runtime tests that was slightly slower (very very slightly, about .01 seconds on average of my test data over 1000 rows) than the Select Case.

Comment: but why absolute value? Why multiply by 2?

Comment: In VBA, a TRUE value evaluates to -1, which is why the absolute value is there to convert it to positive.  And the multiplying by 2 is so that you can add true/falses together in a multi boolean check to determine what conditions were satisfied.  So if both conditions are false, we get a 0.  If only the first condition is true, we get a 1.  If only the second condition is true, we'll get a 2 (because of multiplying by 2), and if both conditions are true we end up with 3.  The logic can be expanded for any number of boolean conditions.

Comment: Formally, the logic is 2^0*(boolean)+2^1*(boolean)+2^2*(boolean) etc if you want to keep adding booleans in a case statement.

Comment: I copied all your sub but the results are wrong.
Every cell in the "N" column now has value 0

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer something like this, you should be aware where the most time of the execution is spent. I suggest that it is the process of writing in the Excel files here:

```
Cells(i, 14) = Cells(i, 14) + Worksheets("VendutoPassato").Cells(j, 4)
Cells(i, 14) = Cells(i, 14) + Worksheets("VendutoPassato").Cells(j, 4)
```

So, it is a good idea to comment these lines and see whether it works fast enough for you. If the speed is Ok, then try to make some structure, that remembers where something should be written and what should be written. E.g., some kind of an object, that remembers that `Cells(i, 14) + Worksheets("VendutoPassato").Cells(j, 4)` should be written in `Cells(i, 14)`.

Once it is done, try to write everything at once, at the end of the task. Supposingly it should go faster.